# Christmas Themed Adventure

Tags: dnd-4e, game-recommendation, published-adventures

I Watched the Big Bang Theory s06e11 The Santa Simulation. And I wondered whether there are actually Christmas Campaigns, I searched a little but I have no clue which adventures are fun to play. Has anyone here played a Christmas Campaign? Or does anyone know if "the Santa Simulation"is based of a real campaign? I would like to have a short heroic tier 5-6 Player Campaign. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I found several Campaign ideas, but I would prefer an already worked out campaign.

Things I found:

- This is for 2 players only: http://skylandgames.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/a-christmas-carol-dnd-4e-adventure/
  This is only one encounter (and the level is a little to high (lvl 10))
- http://dungeonsmaster.com/wp-content/uploads/Corwin_Riddle_Holiday_Dungeon_Contest.pdf
- A cool (LoTR) Campaign idea: https://web.archive.org/web/20140712064747/http://angrydm.com/2012/11/oh-christmas-treant/

Comment: The 'D&D' in the Big Bang Theory, as far as I can tell, is completely fabricated, so I doubt they used a real campaign.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, but it sounded fun and I can hope :D

Comment: There's almost certainly *something* Christmas-themed out there for D&D, but I'm not sure whether it will suit your needs well.

Comment: Those seems to be more like adventures than like campaigns. Anyway, I don't know how much sense would make a full campaign.

Comment: @Flamma That is a valid point, perhaps a 1-3 session adventure would be best. I hadn't really thought of that yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official Christmas adventure for D&D Gamma World, which is based on D&D 4 rules.  You can find it here
http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20101222

Not really a campaign and not really just D&D, but D&D 4 nonetheless.

Comment: Its not D&D Gamma World, its just Gamma World 4th edition. While Gamma World 4e shares many design similarities with D&D 4e they are in fact different systems, especially in how items, powers, and health  management are handled. You would need to adapt the gamma world adventure before running it.

Comment: Well, actually it is really called "D&D Gamma World". If it had an edition-number, it had to be 7th edition, which is the unofficial name of the game. You can see it here: http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/254600000 and might find this interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_World. You are right about that adventure having to be adapted, though.